# Cancel awaiting itself

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following example code:

```
public static async Task Async()
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    source.CancelAfter(500);
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await RunThread(ExpensiveOperation, source.Token);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}

public static async Task RunThread(Action act, CancellationToken token)
{   //modify this method to handle cancelling the token during the following await
    await Task.Run(act); //Task.Run(act, token) doesn't help
}

public static void ExpensiveOperation()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //simulates CPU expensive operation
}
```

Now, how can I modify the `RunThread` method to actually stop awaiting for the long task, by registering the task being cancelled, and so return after those 500 miliseconds, not waiting for the actual completion of the `ExpensiveOperation`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the token to the operation itself, and check it from time to time:

```
public static async Task RunThread(Action<CancellationToken> act, CancellationToken token)
{   
    await Task.Run(() => act(token), token);
}

public static void ExpensiveOperation(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

You also pass the token to `Task.Run` so the returned `Task` would know it was cancelled and not just faulted.

If you can't cancel from inside the `ExpensiveOperation` (either you can't change the code, or it's actually an asynchronous operation and not a synchronous one) then use the `WithCancellation` extension method:

```
static Task WithCancellation(this Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return task.IsCompleted
        ? task
        : task.ContinueWith(
            completedTask => completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
            cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

```
public static async Task RunThread(Action act, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(act).WithCancellation(token);
}
```

Note that this approach doesn't actually cancel the operation, it just lets your code flow behave as if it did.

Comment: Could the `WithCancellation` method run into troubles if the task was not yet completed when `task.IsCompleted`, but it was before `task.ContinueWith`?

Comment: @IllidanS4 no. You can use always use `ContinueWith`. Checking `IsCompleted` is just an optimization to not bother with the registration since the task completed already.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Proof of concept showing it works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/7niI5W (btw, I deleted my answer because I was looking at the overloads of `Task.WaitAny` instead of `Task.WhenAny`).

Comment: It's a good answer. Someone is trying to annoy you, you should simply ignore it.